# Select columns from dataframe start with number

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with column names with name start with numbers and names with string and I want to subset with names starting with numbers followed by dots.

this code is working for this sample but in my actual data frame the column `AA ID` get selected. I don't know the reason

```
df <- data.frame(`AA ID`=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                 "BB"=c("AMK","KAMl","HAJ","NHS","KUL","GAF","BGA","NHU","VGY","NHU"),
                 "CC"=c("TAMAN","GHUSI","KELVIN","DEREK","LOKU","MNDHUL","JASMIN","BINNY","BURTAM","DAVID"),
                 "DD"=c(62,41,37,41,32,74,52,75,59,36),
                 "EE"=c("CA","NY","GA","DE","MN","LA","GA","VA","TM","BA"),
                 "FF"=c("ENGLISH","FRENCH","ENGLISH","FRENCH","ENGLISH","ENGLISH","SPANISH","ENGLISH","SPANISH","RUSSIAN"),
                 "GG"=c(33,44,51,51,37,58,24,67,41,75),
                 `1A`=c("","D","","NA","","D","","","D",""),
                 `2B`=c("","A","","","A","A","A","A","",""),
                 `3C`=c("","","","","","","","","",""),
                 `4D`=c("","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","",""),
                 "Concatenate" = c("","DAG","G","NAG","AG","DAG","AG","AG","D",""))

df <- df %>% rename(`1. A`="X1A",`1. B`="X2B",`1. C`="X3C",`1. D`="X4D")
Error_summary <- select(df,matches("^[0-9]*\\."))
```

also I am trying to add count in data frames like below

```
df_row = 
  df %>% 
  summarize(across(c(matches("^[0-9]*\\."), Concatenate), ~ sum(!is.na(.) & . != "" & . != "NA")))
```

but this is also selecting column `AA ID` which i dont want to select.

Comment: If possible you should avoid using column names that are not allowed, i.e. starting with a number or containing spaces.

Comment: BTW the data which you have shared does not have columns names that start with number. R changes them and adds `X` in front of them. Is that the same case with your real data?

Comment: yes thats what i can see R is adding X to column names but i dont understand but in actual my column names start like "1. city" , "2. country", "5.  profession"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account that your variables supposed to starting with numbers will be converted to variable names starting with X, you could do:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  select(matches("^X[0-9]"))
```

which gives:

```
   X1..A X2..B X3..C X4..D
1                         
2      D     A           G
3                        G
4     NA                 G
5            A           G
6      D     A           G
7            A           G
8            A           G
9      D                  
10
```

With the same logic you can do your counts:

```
df %>% 
  summarize(across(c(matches("^X[0-9]"), Concatenate), ~ sum(!is.na(.) & . != "" & . != "NA")))
```

which gives

```
  X1..A X2..B X3..C X4..D Concatenate
1     3     5     0     7           8
```

Although I'm not sure if you want to exclude the "NAG" value in the Concatenate column.

Comment: i have tried this but this is also selecting the column `AA ID`

Comment: It does not. Please see how the summarize command in my post differs from your code. Also with your code, column "AA ID" wouldn't be selected because it doesn't start with [0-9].

Comment: in actual column names are 1. city,   2.country like this but in this r is adding x in columns